# Efficiently adding click listener to an arbitrary number of elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to listen for click events on an arbitrary number of elements and inside the click event handler, I want to retrieve some info about the clicked element (info which was easily accessible during element creation).

A common solution to this problem is this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.props.users.map(user => (
        <button onClick={() => this.buttonClicked(user.email)}>
          {user.name}
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The flaw I see in this approach is that we're creating a new function for every element. Is that a problem worth solving? If it is, how do you feel about this solution:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.props.users.map((user, index) => (
        <button data-index={index} onClick={this.buttonClicked}>
          {user.name}
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

buttonClicked(event) {
  const { index } = event.currentTarget.dataset;
  const { email } = this.props.users[index];
  // ...
}
```

Comment: your code looks good! I see no pbms there

Comment: Generally this problem is solved with using a `class` and assigning the click event to elements which have that class (*Which is very commonly done in a library like jQuery*). That way there is only a single function.

Comment: @MarouenMhiri Do you think defining a new function for every element is a problem that deserves to be solved or would it not have any noticeable performance impact even when there are many elements?

Comment: if you asked the same question a couple years ago I would say it could be a problem but nowadays no! It's like doing for(var i=0; i<x;i++) { elem.addEventlister('click', function(){...});}. I mean how many elements do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Create another component and dispatch the event from it.

```
class Button extends React.PureComponent{
  handleOnClick = ()=>{
    const {onClick, ...rest} = this.props
    if(onClick typeof ==='function'){
      onClick(rest)
    }
  }
  render(){
    const {name} = this.props
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleOnClick}>
        {name}
      </button>)
  }
}

...

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.props.users.map(user => (
        <Button {...user} key={user.email} onClick={this.buttonClicked} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is better to use a defined function instead of anonymous/inline functions, otherwise the `onClick` handler only gets created during the render stage.

In your second example, you can actually bind the argument to the handler:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.props.users.map((user, index) => (
        <button data-index={index} onClick={this.buttonClicked.bind(this, user.email)}>
          {user.name}
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Secondly, wanted to point out that there is no performance issue with having many handlers. [**React uses one event handler at the root of your document**](https://www.kirupa.com/react/events_in_react.htm).

Comment: Wouldn't `bind()` create a new function which is the very problem this code attempts to solve?

Comment: Hmmm… totally schooled on this one, did not realise `bind` actually creates a new function! At least I can say that I have not seen issues with the suggested approach at large scale.